# removing reversed duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data={'mol1':['cpd1','cpd2', 'cpd3'], 'mol2': ['cpd2','cpd1', 'cpd4'], 'sim': [0.8,0.8,0.9]})

print(df_in)

   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.8
1  cpd2  cpd1  0.8
2  cpd3  cpd4  0.9
```

The pair (cpd1, cpd2) occurs twice although each element does not belong to the same column.

I would like to get rid of these duplicates to end up with this:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data={'mol1':['cpd1', 'cpd3'], 'mol2': ['cpd2', 'cpd4'], 'sim': [0.8,0.9]})

print(df_out)

   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.8
1  cpd3  cpd4  0.9
```

If I ignore the third column, there is a solution describes in [Pythonic way of removing reversed duplicates in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164630/pythonic-way-of-removing-reversed-duplicates-in-list), but I have to preserve this column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for columns from list `cols` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
cols = ['mol1','mol2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.8
2  cpd3  cpd4  0.9
```

Similar solution with [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
cols = ['mol1','mol2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.8
2  cpd3  cpd4  0.9
```

If need check duplicates only in `cols` add parameter `subset`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'mol1':['cpd1','cpd2', 'cpd3'], 
'mol2': ['cpd2', 'cpd1', 'cpd4'], 
'sim': [0.7,0.8,0.9]})
print (df)
   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.7
1  cpd2  cpd1  0.8
2  cpd3  cpd4  0.9

cols = ['mol1','mol2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
print (df)
   mol1  mol2  sim
0  cpd1  cpd2  0.7
2  cpd3  cpd4  0.9
```